# Is there any way to plot labels in ggplot using two different data sets with different number of columns and rows?

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

I'm trying to plot and metaMDS with the labels (spp) of the distance data.

```
dat<-data.frame(
"site" = c("a", "a", "a",'a', "b", "b", "b", 'b', "c", "c", "c",'c'),
"sample"=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4),rep(3,4)),
"sp1"=c(1,3,3,2,4,2,1,5,3,6,1,5),
"sp2"=c(1,3,3,2,4,2,1,5,3,6,1,5),
"sp3"=c(1,3,3,2,4,2,1,5,3,6,1,5),
"sp4"=c(2,3,4,1,5,3,1,5,5,8,9,1),
"sp5"=c(3,4,3,1,6,7,5,8,3,1,3,2)
)
```

I tried

````
```
dat1<-dat[,3:7]
dmds<-metaMDS(dat1, distance = "bray", autotransform = FALSE)
mds1 <- dmds$points[,1]
mds2 <- dmds$points[,2]
plt<-cbind(dat,mds1,mds2)
spp<-names(dat1)
ggplot(plt,aes(mds1,mds2, shape=site,color=site))+
geom_point()+
geom_text(aes(label=spp), size=3)
```
````

However, a get an error

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (12): label

Because the number of rows of `dat` and rows of "spp<-names(dat1)" are different

Is there any way to workaround this error?

[I would like to have something like this, but with the correct spp number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtkdz.png)

Comment: What is the correct spp number in each case? You have calculated 12 points - each combining the data of sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4 and sp5 for each of the 12 rows. The error comes when you try to assign five labels (sp1:sp5 again) to the 12 calculated points. Do you mean to calculate a point for each column (5 points in total)? Or a point for each site/sample for each column (15 points in total)?

Comment: Sorry, when I said the correct spp number I mean that each point (12 points) of each site have to be label it with one of the sp, however each sp can be in sites a, b or c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a further potential direction - I think you mean that you'll have a separate set of species for each site, rather than the five (sp1:sp5) identical species labelled in each site? Here's a worked example of what that might look like, passing three dataframes to allow for different columns representing three different sets of species:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(vegan)

dat_a<-data.frame(
  "site" = "a",
  sample = c(1:4),
  "sp1_a"=c(1,3,3,2),
  "sp2_a"=c(1,3,3,2),
  "sp3_a"=c(1,3,3,2),
  "sp4_a"=c(2,3,4,1),
  "sp5_a"=c(3,4,3,1)
)

dat_b<-data.frame(
  "site" = "b",
  sample = c(1:4),
  "sp1_b"=c(4,2,1,5),
  "sp2_b"=c(4,2,1,5),
  "sp3_b"=c(4,2,1,5),
  "sp4_b"=c(5,3,1,5),
  "sp5_b"=c(6,7,5,8)
)

dat_c<-data.frame(
  "site" = "c",
  sample = c(1:4),
  "sp1_c"=c(3,6,1,5),
  "sp2_c"=c(3,6,1,5),
  "sp3_c"=c(3,6,1,5),
  "sp4_c"=c(5,8,9,1),
  "sp5_c"=c(3,1,3,2)
)


# Using purrr::map to iterate over lists of dataframes

results <-
  map(list(dat_a, dat_b, dat_c), function(x)
    metaMDS(x[, 3:7], , distance = "bray", autotransform = FALSE))

results %>% 
  map2(c("a", "b", "c"), ~ tibble(
    site = .y,
    species = rownames(.x$species),
    x = .x$species[,1],
    y = .x$species[,2]
    )) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, label = species, col = site)) +
  geom_text()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Baxter. But maybe I have to explain my self better and maybe the df is not clear. Site is where the sample was collected and sample is number of samples per site. I want to label the 12 points with the five species which are sp1:sp5, however is one sp (sp1:sp5) per point or site.

Comment: Do you mean you want to have all five labels attached to every point, so the same label "sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, sp5" as a whole phrase under every one of 12 points?

Comment: I've looked over the documentation for `metaMDS` and I think I see what you're aiming for now - new solution above which might help?

Comment: No, is just one label per point either sp1, sp2, etc. But have to be logical with the MDS result, species (sp) are related to sites.

Comment: I don't think your example dataframe shows this then. Each one of your five species is present across all samples across all sites - every one of your 12 points is calculated from the exact same five species. Maybe you need to do the same `metaMDS` process with three separate dataframes, and then combine the results?